# Configure ASP.NET Core to work with proxy servers and load balancers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have followed all steps explained on [this Microsoft's documents page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-2.1) to be able to obtain remote client's IP address in an IIS-hosted app by calling `HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress` , but I keep getting the loopback IP address of `::1`. There is only one weird scenario that gets me the remote client's IP address and that's by the service configuration code below where `ForwardedForHeaderName` is initialized by `X-Forwarded-For-Custom-Header-Name` which does not make any sense to me!

```
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ForwardLimit = 2;
    options.ForwardedForHeaderName = "X-Forwarded-For-Custom-Header-Name";
});
```

The full [source code is found in this github repo](https://github.com/Umplify/ComingSoon/blob/develop/Umplify.ComingSoon/Startup.cs) and I'd like to know what exact change must be done to obtain the remote IP address successfully by removing "X-Forwarded-For-Custom-Header-Name" and why such a string gets me the IP address!

Comment: What is your proxy server / load balancer setup?  What is the content of `X-Forwarded-For` header?

Comment: Btw I created an [issue for the docs team](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/7515) to make sure the documentation on this is a bit clearer. Feel free to chime in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that `X-Forwarded-For-Custom-Header-Name` is meant to be replaced with a custom header name in case your proxy / load balancer doesn't use the standard `X-Forwarded-For` header but something different.

While `X-Forwarded-For` is the de-facto standard here, some proxies / load balancers use another header. In this case you would set it to the value used by your it, for examle `X-Real-IP`.

In your case, you will have to look at which headers are used in your setup and then configure your application accordingly.

When hosting in IIS using the default hosting model (`dotnet publish` should generate the appropriate `web.config` file), the forwarding is already set up and handled by the IIS middleware.

Comment: Yes, I understand that X-Forwarded-For-Custom-Header-Name is meant to be replaced with a custom header name but interestingly it gave me the IP address of the client while the app is hosted on IIS!

Comment: Ah I see, that's the intention though because the request origin would be the proxy server's address.

Comment: If the IIS is running on the same server, then ::1 isn't unrealistic (localhost IPv6).

Comment: So, what would be the proper way of getting the IP address of a client/user who's using the app from their remote computer in another network? Would the piece code that I copied and pasted in the question work?

Comment: Edited: when using IIS using default IIS configuration, this is already handled and you don't need to add any code.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you expect proxy to forward the original IP address in a header that is different from the usual `X-Forwarded-For` you don't have to specify `ForwardedForHeaderName`, instead configure it as:

```
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ForwardedHeaders = 
        ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
});
```

Comment: I originally did this but it did not get me the IP address of the original IP address of the client.

Comment: Is your proxy configured to produce those headers? If you are seeing up reverse proxy, there is more appropriate [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#set-up-a-reverse-proxy) than the one you linked.